# How to save your html form to excel sheet using java script?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vbscript

I have one html form, I want to store that form data into excel sheet. I am using linux(Fedora 15) OS. I have one VB Script that works for me fine in Internet Explorer, Windows OS. But Same script not working in linux mozilla firefox browser. Please tell me java script for store my html data into excel sheet, that works in linux OS and mozilla firefox browser. I share my VB script please tell me correction in that so i can use it as java script.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script language="vbscript" type="text/vbscript">
Sub Sample()
Dim iRow
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("home/Book1.xlsx")
'Document.GetElementsByName("fname")(0).Value="C#"
'Document.GetElementsByName("lname")(0).Value="Corner"
'Document.GetElementsByName("Add1")(0).Value="Tamilnadu"
'Document.GetElementsByName("Add2")(0).Value="Coimbatore"
objExcel.Application.Visible = True
objWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
set XlSheet =objWorkbook.Sheets(1)
XlSheet.Activate
iRow = 1
With objExcel
Do While .Cells(iRow, 1).value <> ""
.Cells(iRow, 1).activate
iRow = iRow + 1
Loop
.Cells(iRow, 1).value=Document.GetElementsByName("fname")(0).Value
.Cells(iRow, 2).value=Document.GetElementsByName("lname")(0).Value
.Cells(iRow, 3).value=Document.GetElementsByName("Add1")(0).Value
.Cells(iRow, 4).value=Document.GetElementsByName("Add2")(0).Value
MsgBox "Data Added Sucessfully",vbinformation
Document.GetElementsByName("fname")(0).Value=""
Document.GetElementsByName("lname")(0).Value=""
Document.GetElementsByName("Add1")(0).Value=""
Document.GetElementsByName("Add2")(0).Value=""
End With
objWorkbook.save
objWorkbook.close
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing
End Sub
</script>

<body>
<form>
<fieldset>

<center>

First name:<br> 
<input type="text" name="fname" Value=""><br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lname" Value=""><br>
Address1:<br>
<input type="text" name="Add1" Value=""><br>
Address2 :<br>
<input type="text" name="Add2" Value=""><br>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="Sample()" value="Submit" /><br>
</center>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

For this code i have created excel sheet in my computer every time i click on Submit button one row is created and store data in my excel sheet.

Comment: SO is not a free translation service. Please try the translation yourself and come back when you have a question about a *specific* problem.

Comment: I want to store html form into excel sheet. I have VB Script for this, which working correctly but i want Java Script for this because VB script only support in Internet Explorer browser.

Answer (score 0):

Security permissions must be altered to allow saving to a local folder. If you are running this file directly from your machine consider renaming it to .HTA and look at HTML Applications on msdn.com.